# Какая нужна команда, чтобы запустить восстановление базы mariadb при объявлении манифеста kubenetes

Tags: mariadb, kubernetes, manifest

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mariadb
COPY all-databases.sql /base/all-databases.sql
```

**Манифест**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mariadb
spec:
  serviceName: mariadb
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mariadb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mariadb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mariadb
        image: XXXXX/mariadb01:v5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvclocal
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        command: ["mysql", "-uroot", "-ppassword", "<",  "/base/all-databases.sql"]
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pvclocal
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: local-storage
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Наличие такой команды приводит к ошибке в pod

```
command: ["mysql", "-uroot", "-ppassword", "<",  "/base/all-databases.sql"]
```

Без нее создается пустая база

Comment: Согласно документации на образ myriadb (https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) любые файлы с расширением sql автоматически исполняются при инициализации контейнера если они находятся в /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d  Кроме того в той же документации написано как руками выполнять загрузку данных. и там даже написано что запуск идет как `sh mysql ... < ....` и это логично, потому что стрелочку перенаправления ввода (`<`) поддерживает именно shell, а не mysql

Comment: @Mike К сожалению, 'command: ["sh", "mysql", "-uroot", "-ppassword", "<",  "/base/all-databases.sql"]' тоже дает ошибку

Comment: А просто положить файл в нужное место образа не выполняя ни каких команд не помогает ? И когда пишите "дает ошибку", всегда пишите какую именно ошибку дает. Обычно ошибки довольно много сообщают о проблеме

Comment: @Mike Файл резервной копии лежит в образе, из которого создается pod. Но command в таком виде не работает.  'Warning  BackOff    34s (x10 over 2m22s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container'

Comment: Возможно надо создать дополнительный Job. Но как его заставить работать с созданным pod я не понимаю.